# Returning all documents from server request to build list tiles in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, oop, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named "ProductDatabase" that contains documents for all available products.

I aim to make an authenticated request to my server, which will return a snapshot of all the documents.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:redue/pages/menu.dart';
import '../main.dart';
import 'listProducts.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:favorite_button/favorite_button.dart';
import 'map.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class listPage1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const listPage1({super.key});

  @override
  State<listPage1> createState() => listPage3();
}

class listPage3 extends State<listPage1> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;
  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    return Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Album>>(
            future: fetchAlbum(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(snapshot.data![index].productName),
                      );
                    });
              }
              else {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            }));
  }


  }

  Future<List<Album>> fetchAlbum() async {
    String username = 'xxxxxx';
    String password = 'xxxxxxxx';
    String basicAuth =
        'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
    print(basicAuth);

    final r = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(
            'http://0.0.0.0:5000/apiv1/read?collection=ProductDatabase&document=all'),
        headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
    print(r.body);
    if (r.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      return json.decode(r.body).cast<Album>();
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
}

class Album {
  final String brand;
  final int quantity;
  final String SBD;
  final String storeName;
  final String price;
  final String productName;
  final String ID;

  const Album({
    required this.brand,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.SBD,
    required this.storeName,
    required this.price,
    required this.productName,
    required this.ID,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      brand: json["Data"]['Brand'],
      quantity: json["Data"]['quantity'],
      SBD: json["Data"]['SBD'],
      storeName: json["Data"]['storeName'],
      price: json["Data"]['price'],
      productName: json["Data"]['productName'],
      ID: json['ID'],
    );
  }
}
```

Currently, I'm running the server locally and when I run the above code, it throws the "failed to load album" exception, even though my command prompt shows that a request was made and the status code was 200.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the response as a json, not casting as `Album`.

So, something like:

```dart
 if (r.statusCode == 200) {
      var list = json.decode(r.body) as List;
      return list.map((e) => Album.fromJson(e)).toList();
 } else {
 ...
```

By providing sample response, you can test it like:

```dart
void main() {
  var response = '[]';
  var list = json.decode(response) as List;
  var albums = list.map((e) => Album.fromJson(e)).toList();
  print(albums);
}
```

Comment: using that method what edits do I need to make to the _buildListItem widget.

Comment: @ReDue: the changes are the first part of the answer, the ones between the brackets of `if` statement.